# Excel VBA Global Range variable out of scope after sub procedure completes

Tags: excel, variables, range, vba

I am perplexed why my global variable within a module fall out of scope at the conclusion of a sub procedure.

I declare the range at the top of the module out side of all subproc and functions 
as below

```
Option Explicit

Dim TIMEDATA As Range
Dim FREQDATA As Range

Const StartLoc = "B4"
Const flowLoc = "F4"
Const dtLoc = "J8"
```

In my subproc I define one of the ranges.

```
Public Sub PortandConvertData()

<SNIP> 
Set TIMEDATA = calcSheet.Range(Cells(2, 2).Address, Cells(2 + dataSize, 2).Address)

End Sub
```

After the sub completes in the watch window I see the variable TIMEDATA go from 
Range/Range to Range and the value go from correct to simply out of context.

I want to store data in the module rather than pasting in a sheet or something.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Declare them as public.  

Public TIMEDATA As Range
Public FREQDATA As Range

Comment: @MatthewD I tried Global and Public and neither work. Goes to out of context as soon as the sub proc finishes.

Comment: @MatthewD that did not work either.

Comment: Is your code execution stopping and returning focus back to the spreadsheet?

Comment: @MatthewD Yes. I have spreadsheet buttons calling these functions/procs

Comment: It seems like you want a global static variable. I don't think this is available in VBA --- see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806425/public-static-variable-in-excel-vba). My understanding is that variables go out of scope when there's no code running. You could use cells in a worksheet to implement static storage between subroutine calls.

Comment: You need to show the full code for `PortandConvertData()`

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that the Context in the Watch properties includes the Procedure/Module you are actually watching. You can make sure by setting the context to All Modules:

From the Watches panel: Right Click the Expression --> Edit Watch --> From the Context group set Procedure/Module to All.

If this is not the actual issue, then you are having the same issue I'm having from Access VBA.

This thread explains the same:
[ThisWorkbook not holding global variable value to cancel ontime()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760924/thisworkbook-not-holding-global-variable-value-to-cancel-ontime)